# Save / export the whole project in Xcode

Tags: xcode

Is there any way to export or save the whole project in xcode? Or I have to manually save the project containing folder?
Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Save all files in the project? Copy it to another location?

Comment: I wrote a program and I want to write it further but I want to save this version.But I do not find -saveProjectAs or somethink similliar

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I wrote a program and I want to write
>   it further but I want to save this
>   version.

You want Xcode's [snapshot](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-structure_navigator/articles/RestoringaProjectorWorkspacefromaSnapshot.html) facility.

Comment: I'd add a note of caution here; if you use the snapshot facility, make sure you check that it actually restores before relying upon it.
X-Code 4.5.1's Snapshot facility does work as expected here.

I'd recommend either Diago's answer below or using git/svn.

Comment: Update - snapshots seem to be gone: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7471

Answer (score 6):

Simply copy the whole project folder and rename it to whatever you want. The files are stored inside one big folder, so there should be no need to export it or even save as.

I do this often to make backups.

Another alternative is to implement some sort of SCM system like [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) or [SVN](http://subversion.tigris.org/) and then branching it or cloning the solution. This also gives you the ability to rollback etc if required.

Comment: Unfortunately when you zip up your project folder and send it to someone else, the build config and project info etc. is not transferred.